# Counting categorical variables in grouped dataset in R

Tags: r

I am working with a large dataset on the sex, parentage, and species of a group of animals. I need to calculate 1. *the sex ratio per dam* so that I can calculate 2. *the median sex ratio per species*. Each row in my dataset is an individual animal with the mother's ID number attached so I am planning to first group by dam and then by species.
Here is an example of the dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(
  AnonID = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
  Species = c("A","A", "A","B","C","C","A","C","B","C"),
  Sex = c("F","F","M","F","M","F","F","F","M","M"),
  DamAnonID = c(0,1,1,2,2,2,4,4,4,6)
)
```

Note: DamAnonID is the AnonID of the mother and most mothers are in the dataset itself.

I would like to end with dataset like this:

```
Species <- c("A", "B", "C")
MedianSexRatio <- c(.33,.33,1)
```

So the steps would be:

1. Count number of male and female offspring per dam
2. Calculate sex ratio per dam
3. Calculate median sex ratio per species

I am unfortunately stuck at the very beginning. I cannot figure out how to count numbers of males and females per dam. I have been using `group_by` in `dpylr` to group by dam, but can't figure out how to count categorical variables in `summarise` and am not sure of other coding options.
I would appreciate any help on how to count categorical variables (males and females) in a grouped variable (dam) and if there is a simpler way to calculate median sex ratio per species which I could do without focusing first on steps 1 & 2.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @MrFlick I'm sorry, I don't understand the first question. As to the second, I am just trying to get to the ratios. The way I've thought about it was 1. Get number of males and females per dam 2. calculate sex ratios per dam 3. calculate median sex ratios per species. I am stuck on step 1. If you know of a way to skip one of these steps that would be fantastic! Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by median sex ratios per species?

Comment: @Maël I mean the median sex ratio of all the dams of a certain species.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the sex ratio for women per species, according to the species of the mother:

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(SpeciesMother = df$Species[match(df$DamAnonID, df$AnonID)],
         SpeciesMother = replace_na(SpeciesMother, "A")) %>% 
  group_by(SpeciesMother) %>% 
  summarise(SexRatio = mean(Sex == "F"))

# A tibble: 3 × 2
  SpeciesMother SexRatio
  <chr>            <dbl>
1 A                0.667
2 B                0.667
3 C                0
```

Comment: Yes, I assumed so. I assumed sex ratio per species was the number of Females / n(), but that may be wrong

Comment: Maël is correct, they were random just to show the idea of what the formatting would look like @MrFlick I've edited my original question to show the extra steps and to make it  so they are the actual median of the sample data.

Comment: @Maël thank you for the response! I am confused as to what the variable "SpeciesMother" represents in this code.

Comment: SpeciesMother is the species of the mother. In your code, they sometimes differ from the species of Species of the child

Comment: Btw, if you replace "F" by "M", you get the expected output

Comment: sorry for the confusion. The species do not change between mother and offspring but there are numerous species in the dataset (>1000). Do you know of a code I could use where I do not have to enter in the species name itself?

Comment: Please edit your data frame to show that. This is a bit confusing

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm unsure how to fix this as I'm unsure where in the dataframe I imply that?